# How can I get data from $_POST and send to one more page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

From a webform page (page 1)  data comes to php page (page 2) and here I need to get data from $_POST and send it to  my html page (page 3).  Here's what I can do using ajax, but I can't figure out how to send data to one more page.  Is it possible to do without MySQL?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                   var vname = $("#name").val();
                   $.ajax({
                       method: "post",
                       url: "data.php",
                       data: {name: vname}

                   })
                   .done(function(data){
                       $("#dsh").html(data);

                   });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="name"> <button id="btn1">click</button>
            
            <div id="dsh"></div>

        </div>
```

and in the php page.

```
<?php
$name =$_POST['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: You can use sessions

Answer (score 0):

for the first form use html form submission by using action, method ang input type submit

```
<form action="2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="vname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Now for 2.php that is your next form, use your own ajax as explained in the question only you need to send your **$_POST array** as a **Json Encoded String** to your 3.php, **on document ready**

inlcude jQuery for the code to run on document ready.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'3.php',
        data:<?php echo json_encode($_POST) ?>,
        async:false,
        success:function(html)
        {
            console.log('success page 2');
            console.log(html)
        }
        
    });
});
```

For your page 3 you can use

```
<?php
$name =$_POST['vname'];
echo $name;
?>
```